# How to reference a folder inside of a volume, Craft 3

Tags: craft3, assets

How do I reference a specific folder (by name) inside of a specific volume.  I cannot use the folder ID, I must use the folder name because the name of the folder is a variable related to specific entries.

Answer (score 2):

You could run a query to fetch the `folderId` you need based on the name:

```twig
{# Change this to your volumeId #}
{% set volumeId = yourVolumeId %}

{# Change this to your folderName #}
{% set folderName = yourFolderName %}

{# Returns an ID if there is a match, otherwise false #}
{% set folderId = craft
    .query()
    .select(['id'])
    .from('{{%volumefolders}}')
    .where(['=','parentId', volumeId])
    .andWhere(['=','name', folderName])
    .scalar() %}

{% if folderId %}
    {% set assets = craft.assets().folderId(folderId).all() %}

    {% for asset in assets %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```